# Trouble reading from file in java (difficult format)

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to read from a file, and store the values in variables. The problem is that each line in the file is a mix of integers and strings, with an uneven number of spaces/tabs between them. I know what the first 4 elements in the line are, but then there are a sequence of numbers that differs in length (but these numbers are terminated by a 0). I have tried some different approaches, but I can't seem to get it right. First I tried to read a line one by one, split it when it sees a space, and then store the values that does not consist of blank spaces into a new array. This didn't work as it didn't split "well enough". One index in the array could consist of a string, many spaces and then an int. I have tried som other variants of this, but I just can't seem to think of a good way. Is there anyone that could give me some pointers on how to read this sort of file?

Here is an example of a line in the file:
7 Carpet 8   4  5 9    1 2   0

Ex. of split:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
   line = in.nextLine();
   String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
}
```

I also tried using split("\t")

Comment: Can you post the code you used to split it?

Comment: No code No answer!!!

Comment: I have edited and added the split that I used. I have tried so many things that it's a bit hard to post the code. This is my main attempt at least, but when I print it the split doesn't work correctly as I have written in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
line = line.split(" ");
```

with

```
line.split("\\s+");
```

This will split the line based upon white space rather than a single space. This means it will account for multiple spaces, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To split properly when you get to a space you have to use

```
line = line.split("\\s+");
```

This is because " " is considered a special character in Java.
`line = line.split("\\s");` would be used if it was single spaces but to do many spaces do first one.